# logarithm inequality proof

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, logarithms

I'm trying to prove the following

Log($A^m$)> Log$(\frac{B^m}{A^m})$

Where $A \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}$. $m \in [1,\infty]$.

Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: Without the restriction, all conterexamples are still valid.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$$A^{2m}>B^m.$$
I think, now easy to find a counterexample.

I found $A=1$ and $B=2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a further query which makes the question twofold, to prove the first case is/is not true which you did with the counter example. And to prove the inequality holds without the requirement for B>A.

Comment: @user136754 It's also wrong for $A=B=1$. For $A>B$ it's true of course.